# Rails 2.3 - Render Issue on failed validation (one controller to another)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a controller (items) that renders a contact form if an item is searched for and found. The items are find by url parameters. The problem I'm having is that if validation fails, I don't know how to re-render the contact form back into the items controller while maintaining the url parameters.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe use AJAX for contact form. This would be nice for users and it doesn't have described problems.

Comment: Yeah, I'm working on that with RJS but still having trouble with validations. Thanks for the confirmation.